# How to make a user changeable constant?

Tags: c++, windows, passwords, console-application

I want to make a simple console application that will execute some usefull functions that I regularly use for my school (*to check if a number is prime, to write factors of a number, solve a quadratic equation etc.*).

But as I was making it I decided to add some details about the app to make the user interface prettier: to write the name of the app, version ...

I came to an idea to have an admin password which I can type in and then I can modify those extra details or change the password.

But if I have a password that I store like a const variable or a regular variable `const string password = "blablabla;"` every time I run the app it will have the same password `"blablabla"` so **is there a way to somehow change the password and other extra data so the program saves the new values permanently?**

I thought to save all those extra information in some file and then read them from it every time, but then **if the file is changed then the data will be to and I don't want that**. **I want to change the data only with an admin password.** I also thought I can encrypt those information but still thay can be easely changed.

I also thought that the program can open the source code and then modify those initialized values, but then I need to compile that file and I also don't want that.

**I only want an .exe app that will run and can change those information permanently with an admin password.**

**Does anyone now if this can be done and how?**

I'm writing this app in C++.

*Thank you in advance*

Comment: If you're using C++, then why is this tagged C?

Comment: Depending on what OS you are using there are probably suitable APIs you can use for storing preferences, passwords, etc. Please add a tag for your target OS.

Comment: @Biffen I thought this can be solved in C too.

Comment: @PaulR I am using Windows 7 Ultimate, and I have another computer with Windows XP. Is there a chance that it can run on both machines?

Comment: OK - I've added a Windows tag for you now - that should help to narrow down the question a bit.

Comment: @PeraPeric It can be solved in a number of languages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to somehow change the password and other extra data so the program saves the new values permanently?

In theory, you may be able to modify the constants in the data segment of the executable. How to do that is dependent on the executable format. But I would consider that a kludgy workaround and it would be difficult to prevent someone from modifying the executable without the password. What you really want is variables. And you have a good idea for how to initialize the variables:

> I thought to save all those extra information in some file

A good idea. Simple solution, probably appropriate for the scope of your app.

> if the file is changed then the data will be to and I don't want that. I want to change the data only with an admin password.

Then protect the file somehow. You could, for example not give anyone write permission to the file. Or if you're paranoid (this is just a small console app just for you, right?) encrypt it...

> I also thought I can encrypt those information but still thay can be easely changed.

It won't be easy without the key. Sure they can modify the cryptotext, resulting in garbage data, but if you are concerned about that, realize that if they have write access to your files, they can just delete the program itself.

If you want to go this far though, consider storing your data in a full-fledged database which will have authentication and encryption already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Windows resources to your application and then update them run-time.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Nasty - there is no guarantee that your application will be writeable, and trying to modify it may well trigger virus checkers etc. Also you lose all your configuration data whenever you install a new version of your program.

Comment: @PaulR: To be fair, though... this works without a separate store (**if** it works), which is what the OP wants. I'm not sure why a program that checks whether a number is prime needs an admin password though...

Comment: @Damon: it's probably OK for a one-off hack for personal use, but it's not a good solution in general, and since StackOverflow aims to be a useful searchable repository of good quality questions and answers for future visitors (i.e. it's not just about solving the OP's immediate problem) I think this makes this answer a -1.